# Can't Load Tensorflow with DirectML

Tags: python, tensorflow, wsl-2

Using Ubuntu 18.04 via WSL2 and trying to run a notebook. Before I do anything, just while importing I run into some issue with the WSL Tensorflow plugin. At the import line:

"import tensorflow as tf"

I get the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NotFoundError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-8a093fe70906> in <module>
      4 import pandas as pd
      5 
----> 6 import tensorflow as tf
      7 from tensorflow import keras
      8 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py in <module>
    437     _plugin_dir = _os.path.join(_s, 'tensorflow-plugins')
    438     if _os.path.exists(_plugin_dir):
--> 439       _ll.load_library(_plugin_dir)
    440       # Load Pluggable Device Library
    441       _ll.load_pluggable_device_library(_plugin_dir)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/load_library.py in load_library(library_location)
    149 
    150     for lib in kernel_libraries:
--> 151       py_tf.TF_LoadLibrary(lib)
    152 
    153   else:

NotFoundError: /home/andre/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow-plugins/libtfdml_plugin.so: symbol _ZN4absl12lts_2021110213hash_internal15MixingHashState5kSeedE version tensorflow not defined in file _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so with link time reference
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here. I haven't deviated from the official instructions. Windows versions and kernel versions should be fine and I have installed the CUDA drivers on the main machine. I've tried installing and uninstalling a few times within WSL2 because I can get it to work with Windows Anaconda already but no luck.

Has anyone encountered this error?

EDIT: Tried with Ubuntu 20.04. No luck

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.